# Azure B2C Persisted custom claim from API not showing on initial signup, but on subsequent sign ins

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have written a custom policy that will gather some info from the user and validate against an API I wrote. That API will return a value to be store in a claim. All the info the user entered and also the value returned from the API are persisted into the user object after the validation technical profile.

When I am testing the policy, the token that is returned right away after the signup does not include the claim that is returned from the API. When I log back in with the same user, the claim is there.

What I have noticed by looking at the data using the graphAPI is that the value from my API takes about ten second to show up in the user object. If I call the user object in the graphAPI as soon as the user is created, the claims input from the user are populated, but the claim from my API is not. If I call the same user about 5 seconds later, the claim from my API is populated in the user object.

Is there anyway to tell B2C to wait for that claim from my API to be populated before continuing the user journey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the claim as an output claims in the technical profile which is calling your rest api validation technical profile.

As per your comment about the delay - B2C internally does not face the delay like you see using public APIs. So that is not the cause.

Comment: So adding the claim as an output claim on the technical profile that is calling the rest API worked perfectly. I thought if I added it there as an output claim it would be shown on the self asserted page asking the users for that value, but it is not. How is it determined which text boxes will be shown to the user to input values.

Comment: We check if it’s output via VTP, then it isn’t shown on screen.